# What is the word for product price besides "quotation"

Tags: synonyms

Is there any equivalent words to the word 'quotation'?

For instance, I'm asking about *the price* of a service I want.

Comment: This is probably either too broad or unclear. First, there are several alternatives. Easy ones are *a quote*, *a price list*, or *the cost*. Second, it's unclear which one would fit your need best because you weren't specific about how exactly you're going to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be many alternatives. Also, it depends which context you are talking in.

However, *one of the close* alternatives I know is the word *'estimate'*. This fits in your example...

> I'm asking for the *estimate* for the services I want to go for.

One of the meanings of *[estimate](https://twitter.com/English4Indians)* is to calculate the amount.

Also, you may ask directly for the *price, charge, fees, budget, cost, etc.* for the same thing.

Comment: To go into more detail, a quote and an estimate are different. With an estimate, the price might change during the project. For example, I get an estimate to repair my car. After they start, they realize there's extra work that needs to be done. I get billed a higher price than was stated on the estimate. With a quote, the seller is bound by the terms and price stated in the quote.